# How to solve drag and drop in DukeScript?

Tags: javascript, dukescript

The goal is that if you drag the picture from one section (#rightbox) to the another one (#leftbox) and you drop it, then a text appears in a text field.

My HTML until now:

```
<body>
    <section id="leftbox" data-bind="event: {drop: $root.writeText}">
    </section>
    <section id="rightbox">
        <img id="pic" src="some_path...">
    </section>
    <section id="resultbox">
        <input data-bind="textInput:  message">
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.writeText">Text!</button>
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.reserText">Reset</button>
    </section>
</body>
```

This is not working...
However, if I replace the event 'drop' with 'mouseover', then if I move the mouse over the zone of #leftbox, then the function 'writeText' will be triggered.

Why is the dropping not triggering the function?
(bonus question, if the events are called on..something.., then why do we have to use for example instead of 'onmouseover' only 'mouseover')

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution would be to add "ondragover="event.preventDefault()"" in your #leftbox. Then it should work:

My reproduced but not perfect solution:

```
<section id="rightbox" data-bind="event: {drag: setDragText.bind($data, 'my dragText 1'), dragend: setDragText.bind($data, '')}">
    <img id="pic" draggable="true" src="img src 1">
</section>

<section id="rightbox" data-bind="event: {drag: setDragText.bind($data, 'my dragText 2'), dragend: setDragText.bind($data, '')}">
    <img id="pic"  src="img src 2">
</section>


<section id="leftbox" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" data-bind="event: {drop: setMessageWithDragText}">
    Some section content.
</section>        


<section id="resultbox">
    <input data-bind="textInput:  message">
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: writeStandardMessage.bind($data, 'Nothing dragged!')">Text!</button>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: resetText">Reset</button>
</section>
```